# Copy a file without filename in destination

Tags: php

How can I copy `foo/test.php` in `bar/` directory? `copy()` function in php needs a filename like `foo/test.php` -> `bar/test.php`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact, you can use that to get the target file name from source path: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Example #1 basename() example

```php
<?php
echo "1) ".basename("/etc/sudoers.d", ".d").PHP_EOL;
echo "2) ".basename("/etc/sudoers.d").PHP_EOL;
echo "3) ".basename("/etc/passwd").PHP_EOL;
echo "4) ".basename("/etc/").PHP_EOL;
echo "5) ".basename(".").PHP_EOL;
echo "6) ".basename("/");
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
1) sudoers
2) sudoers.d
3) passwd
4) etc
5) .
6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Already figured it out. Use `basename(file)`. This will give you the file name of the file then concat it to your destination like `'bar/' . basename(file)`